# Unity LineRenderer disconnected segments?

Tags: unity-game-engine

It is possible for a single LineRenderer to create multiple disconnected line segments?  I need to create multiple line segments that will all change color at the same time.  I have tried to create a positions array with the segments separated by Vector3.positiveInfinity, but that didn't work.

(Attach this class to an empty gameObject)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CreateSegments : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject board;
    private List<(Vector3, Vector3)> endPoints;
    private int numLines = 8;
    private float radius = 5;
    private float lineLength = 3;
    private LineRenderer lineRenderer;

    private void Awake()
    {
        board = new("Board");
        board.transform.SetParent(transform);
        lineRenderer = board.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        endPoints = new List<(Vector3, Vector3)>();

        for (int i = 0; i < numLines; i++)
        {

            // Calculate the angle of the tic
            float angle = i * 360f / numLines;
            float angleInRadians = angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad;



            Vector3 startPos = board.transform.position + new Vector3(
                Mathf.Sin(angleInRadians),
                Mathf.Cos(angleInRadians),
                0f
                ) * (radius - lineLength);

            var endPos = startPos + new Vector3(
                Mathf.Sin(angleInRadians),
                Mathf.Cos(angleInRadians),
                0f
                ) * lineLength;

            endPoints.Add((startPos, endPos));


        }
        // Create a ticPositions array to hold the pairs of points plus Vector3.positiveInfinity
        Vector3[] positions = new Vector3[endPoints.Count * 3];

        // Turn the ticPositions list into an array for input into lineRenderer
        int iPoint = 0;
        foreach ((Vector3, Vector3) tuple in endPoints)
        {
            positions[iPoint] = tuple.Item1;
            positions[iPoint + 1] = tuple.Item2;
            positions[iPoint + 2] = Vector3.positiveInfinity;

            iPoint += 3;
        }
        lineRenderer.positionCount = positions.Length;
        lineRenderer.SetPositions(positions);
    }


    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You could set the color keys of the gradient to be `Color.clear` or set alpha to 0 on the gradient alpha keys.  This provides up to 8 color/alpha keys, which might be too few in your case.

Comment: I wouldn't think so no .. why not simply have one line renderer per line?

Comment: I got incorrect information from CHAT-GPT that adding a positive infinity value between pairs of vectors would create multiple segments.  I have a compass with 72 tics that need to change color at certain times.  I was hoping to do it without creating 72 new gameObjects and having to interate through the objects.  I will proceed with creating the individual gameObjects with LineRenderers attached to each object.  Humans on stack overflow are much better!